# How to install older arangodb version on ubuntu

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to install 2.6.0 (our solution was built upon it). I am getting error that arangodb doesn't have 2.6.0

```
wget https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/arangodb2/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key
echo 'deb https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/arangodb2/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arangodb.list
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get install arangodb=2.6.0
```

Could you please guide me what is the correct way.

Comment: I see that this version is not listed in Sources files https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/archive/ArangoDB_2/linux/xUbuntu_14.04/Sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the listed version on following link can be installed. https://www.arangodb.com/repositories/archive/ArangoDB_2/linux/xUbuntu_14.04/Sources